# Slick way to solve P(pattern A appears before pattern B) type of problems in a coin toss process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let's consider a fair coin and an infinite toss game. We frequently got asked about how to compute the *probability* of pattern $A$ appearing before pattern $B$ where $A$ and $B$ are both one of the eight strings $\{H, T\}^3$. In principle, these can all be solved by Markov chains or first step analysis. But both these two methods sometimes can involve a good amount of calculation. Therefore:

**Question**: is there any slick, non computation-intensive approach that can solve this whole type of problems? (Let's restrict ourselves to $\{H,T\}^3$ for the time being and not consider longer patterns)

---

A friend of mine suggested a nice solution to find P(THH before TTT):

[image]

Explanation:

Since first toss = H means start over, we don't have to handle this event. If first toss = T, the binary tree of events is graphed as above, and we see that among all the cases that result in a determined outcome (i.e. not start-overs), the chances of $THH$ appearing first to that of $TTT$ appearing first is $(1/4 + 1/8):(1/4) = 3:2$.

How do we conclude then the required probability = $3/5$? The way I see it is that the above tree actually defines a "fractal structure" on the whole probability space: among all the "start over" branches, the ratio of the chances of $THH$ appearing first to that of $TTT$ appearing first is always $3:2$. Thus the overall ratio is also $3:2$, hence the conclusion.

---

However, the above only works when $A$ and $B$ have a common prefix. If instead we want $THH$ before $HTH$ then it doesn't apply because there is no more "start over" states I guess. Also, the above approach suffers from lack of explainability and mathematical clarity (e.g., how is one supposed to explain the intuition like "fractal structure" to someone unfamiliar with this problem?)

So is there any better approach that is more widely applicable, more explainable or more efficient? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, one slick method is finding recursive formula for the probability as per your friend's method (see "start again")

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee unfortunately I don't think it works for differently prefixed patterns. there'd be no start overs.

Comment: the recursion method works but the state transition can be much more complicated (and if too complicated it may become not worthwhile).  e.g. in your THH vs TTT example, all "restarts" go back to the original T state.  this is not necessarily true.  e.g. if you were comparing TTTT vs THTH, a "non-decisive" sequence like THTT would go back to the TT state, while a "non-decisive" sequence like THH would go back to the original T state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fun way to solve this is with martingales. I'm going to give the intuitive explanation, although it's not hard to make this perfectly mathematically rigorous. Also I apologize in advance for the length of this answer, but I will try to justify at the end why this is a useful way of thinking.

**The scheme:** A dealer flips an infinite sequence of coins until the sequence THH or HTH comes up. There are two lines of bettors -- call them line A and line B.

Line A is full of bettors hoping to see THH. Here's how this works -- bettor #1 ("Aaron") first approaches the dealer and places a $\$1$ bet at even odds on the first coin being T. If he wins, he'll then hold $\$2$, and he'll bet the whole thing on the next coin being H. If he wins *that*, he'll bet his $\$4$ on the next coin being H. Should that happen as well, he'll take his $\$7$ profit (since one of the dollars was his) and leave happily; the entire game will shut down for all players.

Behind bettor #2 is another better ("Barb") who bets in the exact same way, but one coin behind Aaron, and bettor #3 ("Carl") behaves the same way; so does every other person in the line.

Let's examine how this would play out. Suppose the dealer's string of coins is **THTTHH**
in that order. Aaron bets first; he wins his first bet since the first coin was T! He also wins his second bet... only to lose his third bet and leave with a net loss of $\$1$. Barb has the same fate, but faster; she loses her initial dollar immediately. Carl wins one game but loses the second, suffering the same eventual fate. The fourth bettor ("Diana"), however, is destined to win, and she will leave with a net of $\$7$. Note that two more bettors follow her ("Eva" and "Frank") who each immediatley lose their first dollar.

Now, to line B. These bettors are hoping to see HTH, and will place the same kinds of bets with the dealer on the same sequence of coin flips... *but will do so in the opposite direction.* That is, the dealer will offer *his* dollars and place double-or-nothing bets on H, T, H in that order.

Here's how this would play out with the above sequence of coin flips. The first bettor ("Mike") immediately takes a dollar from the bettor, because the first coin was T instead of the H he was looking to see. (Remember, it's the same structure of bet as with line A, but the coin sequence is different, and the direction of wins and losses are flipped.) The second bettor ("Nelly") pays a dollar to the dealer after seeing H, and then pays two dollars to the dealer after seeing T, but gets all her money back (plus a dollar profit) when the next T comes. Hopefully you see the key insight here: **The fate of every bettor is the same, except for possibly the last three before the game ends.** In this case, only the last bettor of line B is still in play when the game ends, and that bettor will pay one dollar to the bettor (net).

The other key insight is that every bet placed is fair, which means that on average, the net holdings of the dealer don't change (see the technical justification below). This is pretty useful, because the game ends in precisely two ways that we can analyze carefully. Again, note that all bettors before the last three in either line are irrelevant; the dealer has taken $\$1$ from each line A bettor and has given $\$1$ to each line B bettor. So, what happens to the last three in each line?

1. If the game ends in a THH sequence as above, then from line A the last three bettors take $7$, $-1$, and $-1$ dollars from the dealer. The line B bettors take $1$, $1$, and $-1$ dollars from the dealer. Thus, the dealer pays out $\$6$ in this case.
2. If the game ends instead in a HTH sequence, then the last three line A bettors take $-1$, $3$, and $-1$ dollars from the dealer while the line B bettors take $-7$, $1$, $-1$ dollars from the dealer (total payout: $-\$6$).

Let $p$ denote the chance that THH comes before HTH. The dealer's expected net payout is then $$\mathbb E[\text{payout}] = p \cdot 6 + (1-p) \cdot (-6)$$ but since all bets were fair, this expected payout should be $0$. Thus, $$0 = p \cdot 6 + (1 - p) \cdot (-6) \implies \fbox{$p = 1/2$}$$
for these particular sequences.

**Why I love this approach:** It's quick and easy to analyze any head-to-head matchup of any 3-coin sequence. But notice how quickly you could generalize this to a 4-coin streak as well! For head-to-head matchups of $n$-coin streaks, your only task is to carefully analyze the behavior of the final $n$ bettors.

**But wait! There's more!** You can also use this betting scheme to think about other interesting questions. Want to know the expected number of throws before seeing HTH? Just consider one line of HTH bettors and count the profit that the dealer has made at the end. Want to know the expected wait time for the first of HTH and THH? Have two lines of bettors, but let both lines place bets in the normal direction (i.e. how line A behaved in the example I outlined). Want to discuss drawing letters randomly from A to Z and waiting for the sequence ABRACADABRA? Play the same game, but adjust the payout ratios of the bets to be 25:1 instead of 1:1. This is an incredibly powerful approach that generalizes really well and requires only minimal computational complexity.

**Technical justifications:** The fact that every wager placed with every bettor is fair, implies that the net holdings of the dealer constitute a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)). The [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) applies in this case because the stopping time can be shown to have finite expectation -- it can be dominated by a geometric random variable, for instance -- and the increments of the martingale are bounded.

Comment: One more addendum: the problem you're referring to is often called Penney's Game. If you want to see the full matrix of advantages of any 3-coin sequence over any other 3-coin sequence, you can find them here: https://plus.maths.org/content/os/issue55/features/nishiyama/index

Comment: Thanks. I know martingale and optional stopping theorem etc. It's nice to be able to encompass such problems nicely within the martingale framework.

Comment: Ah, good -- I wasn't sure about your familiarity with martingales so I tried to write it from a nontechnical perspective and include all the necessary background, but I'm glad it wasn't needed!

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still a bit ambiguous to me what the martingale and the stopping time precisely are in the application of the optional stopping theorem. Would you care to elaborate a little bit? (It's okay to be purely technical/mathematical/probabilistic and leave aside the gambling/betting background etc.) Thanks.

Comment: Sure -- see 17.3.2 of the following as a reference: https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Though it's still based on a context of gambling, I'll try to make it gamble-free.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems to me that what you're looking for is at the top of page 235 (starting with "We describe the situation a bit more precisely.") The gambling metaphor persists to guide the intuition, but the messy variables and stopping times are there.

Comment: Thanks. I think I followed through, but I also think the formulations in that section are rather sloppy. Not sure if I'm missing anything, but: It never convinces me why $N_t^s$ is a m.g. (because in the def of $A_t^s$, $\tau > t$ isn't predictable, and I think it's a typo and should have been $\tau \ge t$), and also the part they concluded $\Bbb E(\tau) = 2 + 8$ from the fact that $N_t^s$ is a m.g. is extremely confusing, in which I think they actually used $\sum_{s=1}^{\tau} N_t^{s}$ instead (if the sum is still a m.g., which I think is true).

Comment: In conjunction with your answer, I think the general way to solve this type of problems is as follows: 1). If computing $\Bbb E(\tau_{\text{pattern}})$, we should only consider one line of bettors betting on this pattern, and one dealer, and the net payout (or income) of the dealer $\sum_{s=1}^{\tau}N_t^s$ and apply optional stopping theorem on this m.g.; 2). If computing $\Bbb P(\text{pattern A before pattern B})$, we should *two* lines of bettors betting respectively on $A,B$ with one dealer, and the total payout (m.g.): $\sum_{s=1}^\tau (N_t^{A,s}-N_t^{B,s})$ then apply optional stopping.

Comment: Incidentally, I used your approach to get the same answer as obtained by my "tree approach". And it turns out your approach is much more easier to implement into computer programmes and much more easily generalisable to longer equal-length competing patterns.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but I found a technical issue of applying optional stopping theorem when we want to get $\Bbb E(\tau)$ i.e. when there's only one line of bettors and the dealer's payout up to time $t$ is $\sum_{s=1}^t N_t^s$ which we use as the martingale. However, in such a setting it seems that none of the three [conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) for discrete time optional stopping theorem applies. Clearly, (a) and (c) fail, (b) is true but we do not know $\Bbb E(\tau) < \infty$ *a priori* so we cannot use it either...

Comment: You can argue that $\mathbb E(\tau)$ is dominated by a geometric value (hence, has finite expectation), as follows: when waiting for a length-$n$ sequence, break the time interval into size-$n$ increments -- i.e. $[0, n-1], [n, 2n-1], \dots$. The probability that the sequence will occur in any particular block is strictly less than one, and since the blocks are disjoint, these occurrences are independent. Thus, the sequence will occur in such a block eventually, the wait time for it will be finite because this is a geometric variable, and the time for that to occur will bound $\tau$.